# What preposition is needed between the verb "to show up" and a specified period of time?

Tags: prepositions

"He showed up only **on** the very last lesson of this semester"

or

"He showed up only **in** the very last lesson of this semester"?

What's the correct preposition here?

Comment: "**at**" respectively?

Comment: @SovereignSun - Thanks, but what does "respectively" mean in this case?

Comment: I'd probably say "show up **for**", since the student is showing up **for** a particular event (the last class of the semester).